# How to update Poetry plugins?

Tags: python-poetry, python-polylith

According to [Poetry documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/):

- In order to get the latest versions of the dependencies, you should use `poetry udpate`
- And to update Poetry version in its current runtime environment, you can run `poetry self update`

But what is the command, or at least the recommended way, to **update [plugins](https://python-poetry.org/docs/plugins/)**, such as [Polylith Plugin](https://pypi.org/project/poetry-polylith-plugin/), once installed?

Comment: maybe `poetry self add poetry-polylith-plugin@latest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be a specific update command, as of the time of this post.

As suggested by *sinoroc*, you have to reinstall the plugin into its latest version:

```bash
poetry self add [plugin]@latest
```